# XAML design: drawing a line from button to button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to learn XAML and am creating a simple app based off this:

[image: design]

I have created the buttons for each of the circles, but where I am running into an issue is the drawing of the lines and autosizing them to the button positions.  I was wondering if there is a way to bind the start/end point of a path to a button location?  Is there a better way doing this in XAML?

Here is what my current XAML code is...

```
<Page
x:Class="PennyGame.GameControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PennyGame"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="540,133,0,535" Name="Button_Top1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Path Data="M49,100 L48,401" Fill="Gold" Height="302" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Gold" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="2"/>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="725,133,0,535" Name="Button_Top2">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="725,534,0,134" Name="Button_Bottom2">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="540,534,0,134" Name="Button_Bottom1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="434,244,0,424" Name="Button_Left1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="434,423,0,245" Name="Button_Left2">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="831,244,0,424" Name="Button_Right1">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="831,423,0,245" Name="Button_Right2">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Path Data="M526,475 L826,475" Fill="White" Margin="534,0,539,292" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Height="10" />
    <Path Data="M526,295 L826,295" Fill="White" Margin="534,294,538,0" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Height="2" />
    <Path Data="M590,235 L590,535" Fill="White" Margin="590,233,0,233" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="2" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Path Data="M775,235 L775,535" Fill="White" Margin="0,233,590,233" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="3" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Path Data="M590,535 L826,295" Fill="White" Margin="590,294,539,238" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>
    <Path Data="M775,535 L526,295" Fill="White" Margin="534,296,589,233" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>
    <Path Data="M526,475 L775,235" Fill="White" Margin="534,233,589,291" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>
    <Path Data="M590,235 L826,475" Fill="White" Margin="590,233,540,291" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick to handle it in XAML using grids you can use a canvas for each button-line-button constellation.

I'd recommend to handle it in code.

See my example bellow.
I bound actual Canvas properties to each button and the connector line.
It should properly if you resize the container grid, or reposition your canvas.

RESULT:

[image]

CODE:

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">    
    <Canvas x:Name="lineCanvas1">
        <Line x:Name="line" Fill="Green" Stroke="Green" UseLayoutRounding="False" X1="1" Y1="1" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=lineCanvas1}" Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=lineCanvas1}" />

        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button One" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" Height="100" Width="100"/>

        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button Two" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-100,-100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=lineCanvas1}" Canvas.Top="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=lineCanvas1}" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" Height="100" Padding="0" Width="100"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works.  The biggest improvement was using the canvas.  Then the lines resized as needed.  Thank you for the help!